# Change the Input value of a component from another component

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have two components HomeComponent and UserComponent. The UserComponent is a child of the HomeComponent and looks like this:

UserComponent.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div style="display:block">
    <label style="display:block">Search:
      <input #filterString formControlName="filterString" type="text"  id="testInput" class="ui-corner-all">
    </label>
  </div>
  <p-dataTable>
  //Primeng datatable...
  </p-dataTable>
```

UserComponent.ts:

```
    @Component({
     selector: 'user',
     templateUrl: './user.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
     })

  export class ProjektAuswahlComponent implements OnInit { 
     form = new FormGroup({
        filterString: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
     })

     constructor(/*possible services*/) {
     }

     ngOnInit() {
     //do something...
     }
     get filterString() { return this.form.get('filterString') };

     clearInput(){
     this.filterString.setValue('');
    }  
    }
```

And this is how the HomeComponent looks like -->

HomeComponent.html:

```
<!--
some other stuff like buttons and paragraphs...
<button id="userBtn" class="someCssStyles">OpenUser</button>
--> 
<p-dialog id="homeDialog" styleClass="random" closeOnEscape="true" [contentStyle]="{'overflow':'auto'}"
    [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="650" height="auto" [responsive]="true" [resizable]="true" (onShow)="showDialog()" (onHide)="hideDialog()" >
    <p-header>
        <div style="text-align: center;">My First Header</div>
    </p-header>
    <user></user>
</p-dialog>
```

HomeComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

//Show / hide Dialog
public display: boolean = false;

constructor(/*possible webservices service*/){}

ngOnInit(){
/*load data from service class*/
}

showDialog(){
this.display = true;
}
hideDialog(){
this.display = false;
}
```

When you open the website you will first see the Homecomponent which has some buttons displayed and a hidden Primeng dialog. When you click the Button the `dialog` will open which will render the `User template` inside that dialog.
Now inside the Usertemplate i have a input field with which i can filter a datatable, the **goal** is to clear that Input fields value when the dialog closes. The dialog has a callback event called onHide which should somehow do the trick. 
But the problem is that i dont know how to tell the UserComponent that the dialog which is inide the Homecomponent has closed.

> The question now is how can i clear that UserComponents Input Value
>   from the Homecomponent when the Dialog closes?

I tried creating a UserComponent instance inside the Homecomponent and call a function to clear the value but that didnt work it did execute the method but the view didnt update. It looked something like this:

HomeComponent.ts:

```
//imports
//@Component
//etc.
constructor(private userComponent: UserComponent){
userComponent = new UserComponent();
}

hideDialog(){
this.userComponent.clearInput();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use onHide callback from dialog to set the flag  inside HomeComponent. Pass the flag to UserComponent, check if it is true (dialog closed), then make your action and use event emitter to inform HomeComponent to change flag to false.

To check flag inside UserComponent you can use lifecycle ngOnChanges().

2) You can also use ViewChild inside HomeComponent

```
 @ViewChild(UserComponent)
  private userComponent: UserComponent;
```

and then

```
onHide() {
// Clear imputs
this.userComponent.name = '';
}
```

Comment: thank you the @ViewChild notation did the trick thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an event on your dialog component :

```
@Output()
private hideEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

onHide() {
    hideEvent.emit(true);
}
```

You can then listen for this event an do whatever you want from the parent component :

```
<p-dialog (hideEvent)="someFunction()" >
</p-dialog>
```